# Loop violin plots of controls with clinical case data points overlaid (ggplot)

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

New to posting on here. Apologies if I miss including something needed to solve my situation.

I have a matched case-control design where three 'younger' clinical cases have been age-matched to a 'younger' control group, and three 'older' cases have been matched to an 'older' control group. I am plotting the control group distribution in a violin plot and overlaying the corresponding matched cases as  data points.

I have a lot of variables and I would like to loop through them to minimise error and increase efficiency. I have had a go at writing the code for the loop but I am not sure what to do with the fact that I have two types of plots (violin and point) and two data frames (controls and cases) involved.

**Here is the code I have for the plots:**

#fake data

```
cases <- data.frame(
  id = factor(1:6),
  strange_stories_ToM_mean = sample(6:8, 6, replace = TRUE),
  age = factor(c(rep("young", 3), rep("old", 3)))
)
controls <- data.frame(
  id = 7:23,
  strange_stories_ToM_mean = sample(c(6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9), 17),
  age = c(rep("young", 9), rep("old", 8))
)
```

#plots

```
ggplot(data = controls, aes(strange_stories_ToM_mean, age)) + 
  geom_violin(
    trim = FALSE, 
    alpha = 0.2, 
    draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75), 
    fill = "gray90"
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = cases, 
    aes(colour = id, shape = id),  # map color/shape to individual cases
    size = 5,
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16, 17, 15, 16, 17, 15)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("deeppink1","indianred3", "blueviolet", "springgreen3", "chartreuse2", "darkgreen")) +
  scale_size_manual(values=c(5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5)) +
  theme_classic() 

ggsave("strange_stories_ToM_mean.svg", width = 8, height = 8, units = "cm")
```

I looked at using 'for' and created a list to loop through (what I have is below) but I came unstuck at where the list should be incorporated when two data frames are being used and two plots...could lapply be best?

```
variables <- list()                   # Create empty listfor(i in ncol(FTD_data)) {            # Using for-loop to add all columns tolist variables[[i]] <- FTD_data[ , i]}

names(variables) <- colnames(FTD_data) #rename list elements with variable names from df

for (i in variables)
{CODE TO PLOT INSERT HERE}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach to achieve your desired result would be to put your plotting code inside a function which takes one argument, the name of the column to plot. The only change I made to your plotting code is to replace the hardcoded `strange_stories_ToM_mean` by `.data[[col]]` to tell ggplot I want to plot the data column whose name is stored in `col`.

Also, instead of using a `for` loop I would recommend to use `lapply` when using `ggplot2`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

plot_fun <- function(col) {
  ggplot(data = controls, aes(.data[[col]], age)) + 
    geom_violin(
      trim = FALSE, 
      alpha = 0.2, 
      draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75), 
      fill = "gray90"
    ) +
    geom_point(
      data = cases, 
      aes(colour = id, shape = id),
      size = 5,
      show.legend = FALSE
    ) +
    scale_shape_manual(values=c(16, 17, 15, 16, 17, 15)) +
    scale_colour_manual(values=c("deeppink1","indianred3", "blueviolet", "springgreen3", "chartreuse2", "darkgreen")) +
    scale_size_manual(values=c(5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5)) +
    theme_classic()  
}

cols_to_plot <- names(controls)[!names(controls) %in% c("id", "age")]
names(cols_to_plot) <- cols_to_plot

p <- lapply(cols_to_plot, plot_fun)

lapply(cols_to_plot, function(x) ggsave(paste0(x, ".svg"), plot = p[[x]], width = 8, height = 8, units = "cm"))
#> $strange_stories_ToM_mean
#> [1] "strange_stories_ToM_mean.svg"
#> 
#> $strange_stories_ToM_median
#> [1] "strange_stories_ToM_median.svg"

p
#> $strange_stories_ToM_mean
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> $strange_stories_ToM_median
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
set.seed(123)
cases <- data.frame(
  id = factor(1:6),
  strange_stories_ToM_mean = sample(6:8, 6, replace = TRUE),
  strange_stories_ToM_median = sample(6:8, 6, replace = TRUE),
  age = factor(c(rep("young", 3), rep("old", 3)))
)
controls <- data.frame(
  id = 7:23,
  strange_stories_ToM_mean = sample(c(6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9), 17),
  strange_stories_ToM_median = sample(c(6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9), 17),
  age = c(rep("young", 9), rep("old", 8))
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked beautifully. I want to save the plots as well. I had the ggsave line of code above. To avoid hard coding it and include it in the loop, would it be: ggsave("cols_to_plot.svg", width = 8, height = 8, units = "cm")

Comment: See my edit. My approach would be to assign the list of plots to a variable and use a second lapply to save the plots.

Comment: sorry to ask another question - I am looking to set the x-axis to be consistent on all plots created by the loop. I can't get it to work though. I was wondering if it should be some sort of 'xlim' argument in the aesthetics of ggplot or something like the following in the violin_plot arguments 'scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-2, 100)'...I am testing out min and max values at this stage, hence -2 minimum and 100 max.

Comment: Basically you already have found the solution: The limits argument of the scale. (But there is also xlim() and ...). Instead of testing various values I would compute the limits via range(), e.g. `xlims <- controls[cols_to_plot] |>  tidyr::pivot_longer(everything()) |> dplyr::pull(value) |> range()`.

Comment: So I have added xlim to violin plot arguments:
`plot_fun <- function(col) {
 ggplot(data = controls, aes(.data[[col]], age)) + 
 geom_violin(
 trim = FALSE, 
 alpha = 0.2, 
 draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75), 
 fill = "gray90",
 xlim(-10,100)
  ) +` 
But I receive this error: `Error in validate_mapping(): ! mapping must be created by aes()`. I've checked that 'aes' is within ggplot, tried adding `mapping=` before 'aes'. The error has only occurred after adding the xlim argument. Do I need to add the same limits to the geom_point? Sorry, beginner here!

Comment: No. We are not talking about base R plotting. (; You set the limits via `scale_...(... limits = ...)` or via `ggplot(...) + geom_xxxx(...) + xlim(....)`.